# Chpt 14 Automate the boring Stuff

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Ezsheets through IDLE and I managed to set it up ok, but when I go to open a Google sheet I keep having this error come up. Have I put the file in the wrong place? I tried re-downloading the credential-sheets.json to no avail.

```
>>> import ezsheets
>>> ss = ezsheets.Spreadsheet('1yX5ysHDlc086WnjNWX_4RVAYKqefW9YrBTVWzGIQS2Q')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    ss = ezsheets.Spreadsheet('1yX5ysHDlc086WnjNWX_4RVAYKqefW9YrBTVWzGIQS2Q')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\ezsheets\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    init()  # Initialize this module if not done so already.
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\ezsheets\__init__.py", line 1669, in init
    raise EZSheetsException(
ezsheets.EZSheetsException: Can't find credentials file at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\credentials-sheets.json. You can download this file from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python  and clicking "Enable the Google Sheets API". Rename the downloaded file to credentials-sheets.json.
```

Comment: Have you put the file in the place that is mentioned in the error message or in a different place? Have you renamed it to `credentials-sheets.json`?

Comment: Hi, I realised that some of the file pathway was in hidden folders, so it's all sorted now. Thanks